# C++11 Geany setup

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, geany

I am learning C++ and I need to properly setup my compile and build commands in Geany for C++11.

I thought I had them correct, but when using `auto`, I receive the following error:

```
warning: ‘auto’ will change meaning in C++0x; please remove it [-Wc++0x-compat]
```

Here are my current set build commands:

```
Compile:  g++ -Wall -c "%f"
Build:  g++ -Wall -o "%e" "%f"
Execute:  "./%e"
```

What do I need to set these to in order to properly compile, build, and execute a C++11 program?

Comment: I think you need to compile under the c++11 standard, using a compile flag something like `-std=c++11`.

Comment: Try `-std=c++0x` option to gcc.

Comment: Whether you should use `-std=c++0x` or `-std=c++11` will depend on your gcc version. The `c++11` variant was added in gcc 4.7 but I believe the old `c++0x` will continue to work. To determine your gcc version simply use `gcc --version`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As what is pointed out in the comments, you need to add the flag `-std=c++0x`. You can set it in the "Build" -> "Set build commands", then modify the commands in following boxs:

Compile:

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++0x -c "%f"
```

Build:

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++0x -o "%e" "%f"
```